# How do I rewrite a URL with multiple variable "directories" in different possible constellations?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I want to get the following rewrites to happen:

- *example.com/dests/?refs* -> *example.com/redir.php?dest=dests&ref=refs*
- *example.com/?refs/dests* -> *example.com/redir.php?dest=dests&ref=refs*
- *example.com/?refs* -> *example.com?ref=refs*
- *example.com/dests* -> *example.com/redir.php?dest=dests*

Currently I have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/([^?].*)/$ /?ref=$1 [S=3]
    RewriteRule ^/[?](.*)/$ /redir.php?dest=$1 [S=2]
    RewriteRule ^/([^?].*)/[?](.*)/$ /redir.php?dest=$1&ref=$2 [S=1]
    RewriteRule ^/[?](.*)/([^?].*)/$ /redir.php?dest=$2&ref=$1
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

with the error being that I get a 404 when calling /dests and the rest doing nothing.

I have checked that the regexps are valid (except for changing / to / b/c PhpStorm told me to, but that didn't work either).

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance
Alix aka B00tLoad_

Answer (score 1):

When your redirects are based on `?xy` query string params you need to access the `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#example.com/?refs -> example.com?ref=refs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=&?/]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ ?ref=%1 [R=301,L,NE]
#example.com/?refs/dests -> example.com/redir.php?dest=dests&ref=refs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=&?/]+)/([^=&?/]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /redir.php?dest=%2&ref=%1 [R=301,L,NE]
#example.com/dests/?refs -> example.com/redir.php?dest=dests&ref=refs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=&?/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(dests)/$ redir.php?dest=$1&ref=%1 [R=301,L,NE]
#example.com/dests -> example.com/redir.php?dest=dests
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ redir.php?dest=$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

I've tested the rules, however, you might need to make small adjustments. E.g. you may need to specify `^index\.php$` (or whatever your default document is) instead of `^$`.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it, and everythin works except for the /dests/refs path, for that I get a 404.

Comment: I meant the /dests/?refs fancy url

Comment: Hm, it's working for me.. I made a small edit, it should not matter. Can you tell where you end up when you go to `http://example.com/dests/?refs`